# How to get the value of the arguments of the sonar tree

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm writing a custom rule for SonarQube for java, I want to check if the value of an argument is qualified. For example, I want to know if the String fit the specific pattern. I can only test if the argument is a String, but I can not get the exact value. Does the API allows me to do so?

For example, for the code below

```
log.error("errorID:210134 It's an error");
```

Can I get the argument and test if the string contains errorID?

Besides, can I get what variable did the method invocation?

For example, for the code below

```
log.error("errorID:210134 It's an error");
```

How can I know that log is an Object of the class Logger?

Comment: System.out.println(log.getClass()); ? Have you even try it?

Comment: it's a custom rule for SonarQube. SonarQube is a software to do the code review, it forms the source code into different kinds of trees. So, it's quite different with simply System.out.println();

Comment: Please don't double post on StackOverflow AND our mailing list. We monitor both channels and it's a pain to have to answer in both places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

- When looking at the argument of the method invocation, check if its kind is a `STRING_LITERAL`, then cast the argument into a `LiteralTree`. From there, you will be able to access its value, as a `String` (Note that it will contain the double quotation marks).
- To check if the invocation was done on a variable, get the `methodSelect()`  expression tree from the method invocation. If its kind is a `MEMBER_SELECT`, cast it to `MemberSelectExpressionTree`. From there, check if the kind of the `expression()` is an `IDENTIFIER`. If it's the case, then you will be able to get the `IdentifierTree` and its associated symbol. You will then be able to say if the symbol calling the method is a variable or not, check its type, etc.